How to properly define a slice knot (or a locally flat disk)?
A knot $K\subset\Bbb S^3=\partial \Bbb D^4$ is said to be (topolopgically) slice if there is a locally flat disk $D\subset\Bbb D^4$ with $\partial D=D\cap \Bbb S^3=K$. As far as I understand, locally flat means that each interior point $x\in \operatorname{int}(D)$ has a neighborhood $U\subset \Bbb D^4$ for which $(U,U\cap D)\simeq (\Bbb R^4,\Bbb R^2)$ with the standard embedding $\Bbb R^2\hookrightarrow \Bbb R^4$.
Local flatness is imposed to prevent choosing $D$ as the cone over $K$. The cone is not locally flat at the cone point.
However, this cannot be the full story. As it is right now, I could first construct $D$ as the cone over $K$ and then contract a path from $\partial D$ to the cone point.
This "moves the local knottedness" from the interior of the disk into its boundary where no constraints are imposed.
This leads me to the following:

Question: How is local flatness defined on the boundary $\partial D$?

I have come across the following idea: call $D$ locally flat at $\partial D$ if there is a locally flat extension, that is, a locally flat disk $\bar D$ that contains $D$ in its interior.
However, I have my problems with this as well. Let $W$ be a small tubular neighborhood of $\partial D$. Construct $\bar D$ by choosing $\bar D\setminus D$ as a small perturbation of $D\cap W$ (that fixes $\partial D$). Then at each $x\in\partial D$ the link should form an unknot, right?

Suppose D is locally flat on the interior and identical to the cone on K in a neighborhood of the boundary.

Sorry, I can't follow. This seems to be impossible to me.

I mean that $${x \in D \mid |x| \ge 1-\epsilon} = {x \in \text{Cone}(K) \mid |x| \ge 1 - \epsilon}.$$ Maybe this meaning was unclear, because this is certainly not impossible; every smoothly (properly) embedded disc can be isotoped to take this form. (I refer to the example of smooth discs here because there is no disagreement about the meaning of smooth proper embedding of a disc into D^4.) Another way to say the same: try assuming the locally flat disc is smoothly embedded in a collar neighborhood of the boundary.

@mme I think I understand. This is a plausible approach! So is this how the definition of "slice" is supposed to be interpreted? Is this standard?

I wouldn't say standard. I would expect this is equivalent to the following definition (up to ambient isotopy): we demand that there exists a neighborhood $U \subset \Bbb D^4$ and a homeomorphism $\varphi: U \to [0,\infty) \times \Bbb R^3$ satisfying (a) $\varphi^{-1}({0} \times \Bbb R^3) = U \cap \Bbb S^3$ and (b) $\varphi^{-1}({0} \times {(0,0)} \times \Bbb R) = U \cap D$. The equivalence would follow from the existence of a well-behaved tubular neighborhood in the case of locally flat embeddings with boundary. I'm not good with references on this, so I hesitate to write an answer.

The question is, what do you want to achieve by local flatness?
One possible answer is the following: You want your slice disk to have a tubular neighborhood. To make sure that you have a tubular neighborhoodhood you need that the disk is a ``topological submanifold'' of the 4-ball, i.e. you want that locally the disk looks likes  $\mathbb{R}^2\times \{0\}\subset\mathbb{R}^4$
or like  $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}\times \mathbb{R}\times \{0\}\subset\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}\times \mathbb{R}^3$. Under this assumption the slice disk is a proper 2-dimensional submanifold of the 4-ball and the slice disk has a tubular neighborhood. This is explained in Chapter 5 of
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1910.07372
